# Neo4J and Cypher query

Tags: graph, neo4j

I am new to Neo4j and Cypher query.My create query is like each Shop has 2 chillers which has 2 PLCs each which in turn has 2 sensors each.

The create is as below

```
Create(:SHOP{name:"Shop1"})-[:hasChiller]->(:CHILLER{name:"Chiller1"})
Create(:SHOP{name:"Shop1"})-[:hasChiller]->(:CHILLER{name:"Chiller2"})

Create(:SHOP{name:"Shop2"})-[:hasChiller]->(:CHILLER{name:"Chiller3"})
Create(:SHOP{name:"Shop2"})-[:hasChiller]->(:CHILLER{name:"Chiller4"})

Create(:CHILLER{name:"Chiller1"})-[:hasPLC]->(:PLC{name:"Plc1"})
Create(:CHILLER{name:"Chiller1"})-[:hasPLC]->(:PLC{name:"Plc2"})

Create(:CHILLER{name:"Chiller2"})-[:hasPLC]->(:PLC{name:"Plc3"})
Create(:CHILLER{name:"Chiller2"})-[:hasPLC]->(:PLC{name:"Plc4"})

Create(:CHILLER{name:"Chiller3"})-[:hasPLC]->(:PLC{name:"Plc5"})
Create(:CHILLER{name:"Chiller3"})-[:hasPLC]->(:PLC{name:"Plc6"})

Create(:CHILLER{name:"Chiller4"})-[:hasPLC]->(:PLC{name:"Plc7"})
Create(:CHILLER{name:"Chiller4"})-[:hasPLC]->(:PLC{name:"Plc8"})

Create(:PLC{name:"Plc1"})-[:hasSensor]->(:SENSOR{name:"Sensor1"})
Create(:PLC{name:"Plc1"})-[:hasSensor]->(:SENSOR{name:"Sensor2"})
Create(:PLC{name:"Plc2"})-[:hasSensor]->(:SENSOR{name:"Sensor3"})
Create(:PLC{name:"Plc2"})-[:hasSensor]->(:SENSOR{name:"Sensor4"})
Create(:PLC{name:"Plc3"})-[:hasSensor]->(:SENSOR{name:"Sensor5"})
Create(:PLC{name:"Plc3"})-[:hasSensor]->(:SENSOR{name:"Sensor6"})
Create(:PLC{name:"Plc4"})-[:hasSensor]->(:SENSOR{name:"Sensor7"})
Create(:PLC{name:"Plc4"})-[:hasSensor]->(:SENSOR{name:"Sensor8"})
Create(:PLC{name:"Plc5"})-[:hasSensor]->(:SENSOR{name:"Sensor9"})
Create(:PLC{name:"Plc5"})-[:hasSensor]->(:SENSOR{name:"Sensor10"})
Create(:PLC{name:"Plc6"})-[:hasSensor]->(:SENSOR{name:"Sensor11"})
Create(:PLC{name:"Plc6"})-[:hasSensor]->(:SENSOR{name:"Sensor12"})
Create(:PLC{name:"Plc7"})-[:hasSensor]->(:SENSOR{name:"Sensor13"})
Create(:PLC{name:"Plc7"})-[:hasSensor]->(:SENSOR{name:"Sensor14"})
Create(:PLC{name:"Plc8"})-[:hasSensor]->(:SENSOR{name:"Sensor15"})
Create(:PLC{name:"Plc8"})-[:hasSensor]->(:SENSOR{name:"Sensor16"})
```

However the Match to get the sensors under SHOP1

```
MATCH(s:SHOP{name:"Shop1"})-[:hasChiller]->(cc:CHILLER)-[:hasPLC]->(pp:PLC)-[:hasSensor]->(ss:SENSOR) return ss.name
```

returns nothing.Says no changes and no data.

I am trying this out on Neo4J sandbox environment.I did this based on the understanding i had using match clause in SQL SERVER GRAPH 2019 where this works.

Can anyone point out where i am going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are improperly creating multiple instances of the "same" node. You should create each node once, and then use its bound variable name later on when you need to create relationships involving that node.

Delete all your data and follow this pattern instead (you have to fill in the "..." parts):

```
CREATE
  (sh1:SHOP{name:"Shop1"}), (sh2:SHOP{name:"Shop1"}),
  (c1:CHILLER{name:"Chiller1"}), (c2:CHILLER{name:"Chiller2"}),(c3:CHILLER{name:"Chiller3"}), (c4:CHILLER{name:"Chiller4"}),
  (p1:PLC{name:"Plc1"}), ..., (p8:PLC{name:"Plc8"}),
  (se1:SENSOR{name:"Sensor1"}), ..., (se16:SENSOR{name:"Sensor16"}),

  (sh1)-[:hasChiller]->(c1), (sh1)-[:hasChiller]->(c2),
  ... // create remaining relationships using bound variable names for nodes
```

Comment: i have a doubt regarding this.wen i do the below query viz.,  MATCH(s:SHOP{name:"Shop1"})-[:hasChiller]->(cc:CHILLER) return cc.name i do get the results as chiller 1 and chiller2. why is it so that it starts failing as soon as i start adding the 3rd condition?Please note this happened for my originally posted query.

Comment: Your first 4 `CREATE` clauses create 4 `CHILLER` nodes. Your next 8 `CREATE` clauses create 8 *totally new* `CHILLER` nodes (which are not the same as any of the original 4). So you have no  `CHILLER` nodes with both `hasChiller` and `hasSensor` relationships. Try using this query to see all your `CHILLER` nodes: `MATCH (c:CHILLER) RETURN c`. You'll see 12 nodes instead of just 2.